# XMLGregorianCalendar time

Tags: java, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I have simple Java program and I want to get just time and get in it. Please, help me.

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
public class JavaApplication1
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        Date trailDate=new Date();
        GregorianCalendar calendar1 = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar1.setTime(trailDate);
        try 
        {
        XMLGregorianCalendar 
        date1=DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar1);
        System.out.println(date1);
        }
       catch (DatatypeConfigurationException ex)
        {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
   }
```

I GET folowing output.

```
  2013-08-30T17:01:35.446+05:30
```

but I want only below output

```
  2013-08-30T17:01:35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the date from the calendar and use `SimpleDateFormat` to format it into a String.

Comment: we will you explain me how to do this?

Comment: @kapil which part are you having trouble with? Getting the date from the calendar or using SimpleDateFormat? Have you looked at the javadoc?

Comment: using SimpleDateFormat

Comment: @kapil Why don't you try to write some code using SimpleDateFormat and let us know how it goes? The javadoc is very good, and there are a ton of examples out there.

Comment: i use SimpledareFormate but i got String Object now how to pass in to..GregorianCalendar as a SetTime() method?

Comment: @kapil Objects like GregorianCalendar don't have a format. Only Strings have a format. You said you wanted to print out the date in a different format, but apparently that's not true. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: i want date and time in XMLGregorianCalendar .tell me please how to do this.. i have one method that will accept only XMLGregorianCalendar value. so how to get date and time using XMLGregorianCalendar.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
System.out.println(date1.toString().replaceAll("(.*)\\..*", "$1"));
```

Comment: replace with text found in group 1 - (.*) that is text before full stop

Comment: i have 2013-08-30T17:25:17.460+05:30 this out put. and i want to remove value after(.)

Comment: i want only 2013-08-30T17:25:17

Comment: Thank you.. i got the My Result

Comment: this is what you'll get, replaceAll will replace 2013-08-30T17:01:35.446+05:30 with 2013-08-30T17:01:35